# failed to start login management in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I updated my system and my pc stuck I reboot it and I faced these problems
There is problem with libraries when I install packages with pacman in chroot with cd boot mode
some packages I want to fix it with pacman -Fy I know this command to know the library which package is related with and reinstall the package it's called vtk but not working
I though there is library have to install first but I don't know what it is
I do this command ldconfig -v
put not works
**This all libraries have the same error in this link below**
https://bpa.st/RRMA 
**SOLVED**

```
pacman -Syyu $(pacman -Qnq) --overwrite '*'
```

you must have free space for packages to check all packages has files corrupted or deleted files to fix it by overwrite corrupted and add what you lost files

---

Comment: Try `pacman -Syyu $(pacman -Qnq) --overwrite '*'`

Comment: Error : Partition / too Full : 828858 blocks needed , 94837 blocks free

Comment: Looks like you need to make some room temporarily, as that command rebuilds all packages in your install ignoring what ldconfig is reporting.  By rebuilding everything, you ensure the system is sane when you finish.  See [here](https://gist.github.com/metzenseifner/cb61ecfd614a93c5927ba3cd62d68127) and [here](https://arch-general.archlinux.narkive.com/pyK47f3b/problems-after-recent-pacman-update)

Comment: I have 1.5GB free on my disk before I have problem with my system , my root partition in total 25GB , 23.5GB used
all packages need 15.706 GB free ,+ upgrade size 842MB

Comment: You could try booting from an Arch install CD mount the filesystems, chroot in, perform the repair, exit the chroot, and reboot, or Delete about 12GB of logs etc

Comment: Thanks I did it , and now I can login 
Thanks @eyoung100